# Replacing values using a filter

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

Let me breakdown what I'm trying to do,

1. Created a filter for my data-frame, in the column NAME_INCOME_TYPE == Pensioner
2. Applied filter
3. Select all NaN values in the column, OCCUPATION_TYPE
4. Replace NaN with 'Retiree'
5. Apply to original data-frame

> But I keep getting the below error,
>
> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame

The code I've written to do the above,

```
filt = app_data['NAME_INCOME_TYPE'] == 'Pensioner'

app_data.loc[filt]['OCCUPATION_TYPE'].fillna('Retiree', inplace = True)
```

Data-Frame I'm using [image]

Comment: You should specify the problem you are facing.

Comment: IDK how you managed to answer my question a second before I posted it :). But you should edit your post to add the warning/error you're getting.

Comment: Hi Yevhen, sorry! I've just added the warning I'm getting

Comment: Sorry. It was incorrect. Fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using `.loc[filter, column].fillna(...)` like:

```
filt = app_data['NAME_INCOME_TYPE'] == 'Pensioner'
app_data.loc[filt,'OCCUPATION_TYPE'] = app_data.loc[filt,'OCCUPATION_TYPE'].fillna('Retiree')
```

should work.